# CngKey.Import on shared hosting where can't enable WEBSITE_LOAD_USER_PROFILE

Tags: .net, .net-core

I'm writing an API in .Net Core which is using Apple Sign In (JWT) and needs to verify the login. Using `CngKey.Import()` requires `WEBSITE_LOAD_USER_PROFILE` to be set on the app pool but my hosting provider says they cannot enable this.

Is there an alternative I can use to achieve the same thing?

The code I'm using currently is

```
  var key = CngKey.Import(Convert.FromBase64String(pKey), CngKeyBlobFormat.Pkcs8PrivateBlob);
```

I've also tried

```
 private static ECDsa GetEllipticCurveAlgorithm(string privateKey)
        {
            var result = ECDsa.Create();
            result.ImportPkcs8PrivateKey(Convert.FromBase64String(privateKey), out _);
            return result;
        }
```

from another stackoverflow post but this has the same issue.

Is there another alternative?